# On Hold - How is it decided whose names are displayed?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-hold

I just recently came across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024937/how-should-i-go-about-making-a-php-and-mysql-forum

I immediately flagged it as `Too Broad`. However, my name did not show up in the text at the bottom of the question.

This is the actual text:

```
put on hold as too broad by Marek Karbarz, Strawberry, Dagon, Mark Baker, Musa
```

I am just wondering why my name did not show up when I was probably one of the first people to flag the question.

Is it because I do not have enough rep (I am only slightly above 2k)?

(Note that I do not care whether or not my name is there -- I'm just curious why it does not.)

Comment: **Close Vote** instead of flagging, to let your nick appear in the close message.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How do I do that? My only three buttons are `"Share", "Edit" and "Flag"`.

Comment: Also why the downvote?

Comment: Downvoting on meta is different from the main SO site. Here, downvotes tend to simply mean a disagreement with your post instead of "this is a pile of rubbish". This is especially true of questions tagged [meta-tag:discussion] and [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @JonK Ah OK. I noticed that I did not lose any rep due to the downvote. Is this the same for upvotes (will I not *gain* any rep due to an upvote)?

Comment: @Jashaszun _'Also why the downvote?'_ Because your question can be trivially solved from the answer available in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: Yes, there is no reputation on the per-site metas like this one. The rep that's displayed is your main site rep, and isn't affected by meta posts in any way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well now that I know that the answer has to do with *close votes* instead of *flags*, the answer is trivially solvable. However, I did not know that close votes were different from flags before now.

Comment: I came to meta just now to ask _exactly_ this question. Thank you for making me not have to go to that effort :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only the names of users who *voted* to close, not of those who *flagged*, will appear in the close banner. They are the ones who are actually responsible for deciding the question should be closed. Your flag does not have the same weight as a close vote: it only alerts users with that privilege to review the question and decide whether to cast a vote.

You'll get the [close vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (and associated re-open vote privilege) when you have 3000 rep.

Answer (score 1):

[You'll need a minimum rep of 3000 to close vote questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) Only the actual close voter's names will appear in the message. . But it's OK you flag them, thus these appear at the review queues.